# NSDictionary with NSNumbers as keys - strange behavior

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary containing other NSDictionaries that I save to a plist.
Its indexes are NSNumbers, made of (pretty huge) integers.

When I re-load the dictionary from the plist and try to iterate it

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in loadedDict){
    nslog(@"dict %@", dict);
}
```

This results in an output containing just the key of the dictionary, but not - as expected - a dump of the dictionary itself.

I have to do the following to get the containing dictionaries:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [loadedDict allKeys];
for(NSString *key in allKeys){
    nslog(@"dict %@", [loadedDict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

And, yes, the keys are really integers converted to NSNumbers...

What's the catch?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast enumeration for dictionaries returns the keys:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

What you are seeing is the expected behavior.

Consider using blocks to get explicit access to both the keys and values:

```
[loadedDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // use key and obj...
}];
```